# A python file can be opened in CMD but can't be opened in powershell

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAHL2.jpg)I have created a python file, it can be opened in CMD but it can't be opened in powershell, computer is WIN10 system, could you please help me to know how to solve this problem? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

In powershell you are in desktop.

You need to do `cd python_work` then `python hello_world.py` to get it working.

Your `hello_world.py` file is in `desktop/python_work` folder. In your cmd test you are first changing directory. In your powershell test you are only changing it to desktop where no `hello_world.py` file.